# Clear document properties as soon as document is unlocked

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

We are acquiring a document lock by using `xdmp:lock-acquire` also we are setting properties like `lockedBy, status, timeout` on the locked document.
we made configuration changes in MarkLogic to release the lock once the time out is done by setting `expunge locks = "automatic"`.

Our requirement is to clear the properties as soon as MarkLogic releases the lock on the document.

We are expecting a solution using trigger not using a scheduled task.

Please help us to find the solution.